# Implode doesn't work in laravel based on variable data

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to implode I use `$occu = implode(',',$_POST["occupation"])` and it implodes and the result is `1,2,4`.

Now when I use `$occu` in query like below:

```
$total = DB::table('store')
->WhereIn('occupation_id',[$occu])
->get();
```

Then it only fetch the id 1 and not the 2 and 4.

But, if I use in this way:

```
$total = DB::table('store')
->WhereIn('occupation_id',[1,2,4])
->get();
```

Then it fetches all three ids.

Therefore, I want to know that why variable based implode first id is taken and not the other two.

Comment: In our second example its array but in you 1st example its string even if u put square brackets around it. For example ["1,2,3"] this is what ur getting with a implode and what are you passing in second example [1,2,3] see the difference.

Comment: If you are already getting array don't implode it just pass it without implode. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, we need to provide array of values for `whereIn` function. But you are providing string with comma separated.

You should use this instead

```
$arrVal = $_POST['ids'];
$items = DB::table('store')
                       ->whereIn('field', $arrVal)
                       ->get();
```

Above is the example code. Please try this.